# Bootstrap 3 button group, trying to get the value of which button is clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Learning Javascript here, just stuck for a brief moment.
I have a button group in html constructed with the following.

```
<div class="button-holder type_of_txt_btn_group" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <label class="btn btn-primary active" value="TE">
                                <input name="text" type="radio" id="txtbutton_id">Text
                            </label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary" name="textbook" value="TK">
                                <input name="textbook" type="radio">Textbook
                            </label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary" name="list" value="LI">
                               <input name="list" type="radio" value="list">List
                            </label>
                        </div>
```

The `value` attribute of each `<label>` is important for filtering purposes. So I want to make a function that, when you click one of the buttons, the function manages to return (or at least use) the value of the label a person clicked on. To check, I wanted to simply use a console.log expression. Ideally I would see either "TE" or "TK" or "LI" in the console.

```
 $(".type_of_txt_btn_group label").on("click",function() {          
       var filteringType = ""
       filteringType = $(this).val()
       console.log(filteringType);
 });
```

But so far this has been yielding what seem to be empty strings in my console and I'm not really sure why at this point. Here is the version I created on fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/12rsob36/1/

Is this returning an empty string and if so why? Is it actually returning the values of the label elements like I would want it to, or is something wrong? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also access the values of the label using `attr()` method. It sets or returns the values of attributes of the selected element.

```js
$(".type_of_txt_btn_group label").on("click", function() {

  var filteringType = ""
  var label = $(this).attr('name');
 // filteringType=label.attr('name');
  alert(label);
});
```

```html
<div class="button-holder type_of_txt_btn_group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active" name="text">
    <input name="text" type="radio" id="txtbutton_id" value="text">Text
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" name="textbook">
    <input name="textbook" type="radio" value="textbook">Textbook
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary" name="list">
    <input name="list" type="radio" value="list">List
  </label>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please refer to the code above.Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the value of a `label` with [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) as it only supports form elements. You can use the [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function instead and set `data-x` attributes to the buttons.

Furthermore the [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) suggests using `<button>` instead of `<label>`:

```js
 $(".type_of_txt_btn_group button").on("click",function() {
       var filteringType = $(this).data('value')
       console.log(filteringType);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-holder type_of_txt_btn_group btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-value="TE">Text</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-value="TK">Textbook</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-value="LI">List</button>
</div>
```